# Can I change the dropdown menu color in react-select (#react-select)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

Can I change the dropdown menu color in react-select (#react-select)?  I actually want to make .Select-menu-outer to be black with white text and .Select-menu to be grey and white text

Comment: Can't you do it with CSS?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45291508/how-to-style-react-select-options

Answer (score 0):

You can either fix this by overwriting default css of react select or by using optionRenderer where you can create your custom options. I think the easier way is to just override the existing classes with css styles. You can do it by referencing those classes like .Select-menu-outer, .favOption, .Select-menu, .Select-option and do whatever you want with them with your own style. just to help you out, if you want to see you menu remain open as it closes as soon as it blur default by nature, you can use react developer tool of chrome and set the isOpen state to true by checking on checkbox. Hopefully this helps.