# How to style this array result in elliptical boxes - CSS

Tags: css

I am working with this demo workspace - [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/jpnm6mwywv)

Here I have an array.

```
var a = [{"id":"firstName","value":["Sam3","Sam5"]},{"id":"lastName","value":["Jones4","Jones5"]}]
```

This is a React based project. I want to show this as a style in the page (instead of an array). I want to show this like this image .

[image]

This is elliptical, and not any irregular shape.

There will be a also a cross button along with the array.

```
<div>
<div>id: val0,val1 (and a cross button to remove this filter)</div>
<div>id: val0,val1 (and a cross button to remove this filter)</div> .... so on
</div>
```

How to display this array in this type of elliptical style

Kindly answer wrt to my [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/jpnm6mwywv) Fiddle

[image]

firstName: Sam2, Sam3 will be in one elliptical box while lastName: Jones3, Jones5 will be in another box. There can be dozens of boxes, I am working with 2 at this moment.

The boxes will be like this

[image]

In the blank area of the elliptical boxes the text will go and then the cross button/icon

Comment: You can customise the styling and icon position too ...please check this https://react-select.com/components

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45291508/how-to-style-react-select-options